# python asyncio class to create functions dynamically and execute with own interval parallel

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.10

I am trying to write a class that create methods dynamically that should executed parallel each with it's own duration with asyncio. But I am really new in the topic python asyncio and now on a point where I got stuck and have no idea how to go.

I collect servers with ip, port and command duration from config file and try to create methods in a loop and then gather these methods with async, here is my code:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
# from common.config import ConfigConstructor


class RCONserver:
    
    def __init__(self, game: str, server_name=None):
        self.game = game
        self.server_name = server_name
        # self.game_config = ConfigConstructor('cfg/rcon_server.yml')

    async def send_rcon_command(self, ip: str, port: str, period: int, cnt: int):
        await asyncio.sleep(int(period))
        print(str(datetime.now()) + ": " + ip + " " + port)
    
    def get_servers(self):
    
        servers = []

        for server in ['game1','game2']:
            print(server)
            if server[:4] == "game":
                # s = self.game_config
                # s.fetch_section(server)
                # print(s)
                servers.append(
                    self.send_rcon_command('192.168.178.1',
                                           '30000',
                                           300,
                                           3)
        
        return servers


async def main():
    obj = RCONserver('game')
    await asyncio.gather(*obj.get_servers())

asyncio.run(main())
```

The code is running but only one time for each server in the yml File.
What do I have to do to run it periodically for the given parameter watch period?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible example of the problem? The code you provided can't be run.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev sry, done! the code runs now but unfortunately not periodically

Comment: Unfortunately your code can't be run, e.g. you have `from common.config import ConfigConstructor` and `ConfigConstructor('cfg/rcon_server.yml')`. How other people can run your code if they do not have your config files?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev sry, I did not understand at first. The code should be running now, the ConfigConstructor simply read a config file for the gameservers with the 4 paramters ip, port, watch_period and cnt. i want to run a parallel functions for each of the server in the config file and each with it's own watch period. not a queue that runs the function one after another, in my example case both with 300 seconds but thats only for the example, later i want to set own watch periods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should do the trick with loop and gather i can create functions dynamically and run each with it's own interval parallel:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import random


class RCONServer:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rcon_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    
    def dt(self):
        return datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    def build_rcon_functions(self):
        rcon_servers = []
        for server in ['game1','game2']:
            rcon_servers.append(
                self.rcon_command(server,
                                  "192.168.0.1",
                                  "30000",
                                  "some_password",
                                  random.randint(5, 10)
                                  )
            )
        
        return rcon_servers
    
    async def rcon_command(self, server: str, ip: str, port: str, passwd: str, interval: int):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(int(interval))
            print(self.dt(), ">", server)
    
    async def run_loop(self):
        rcon_tasks = self.build_rcon_functions()
        try:
            print(self.dt(), "> Start")
            await asyncio.gather(*rcon_tasks)
            self.rcon_loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            print(self.dt(), "> End")
            self.rcon_loop.close()


obj = RCONServer()
asyncio.run(obj.run_loop())
```

Some suggestions for optimizing? or some hints how it can be solved better?